# sequelize postgres поиск в массиве

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

У меня есть таблица users в ней хранятся роли в виде массива

```
  roles: {
    type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.TEXT),
    defaultValue: ['USER'],
  },
```

как найти пользователей у которых есть роль USER?

Comment: Так там `JSON` или `TEXT[]`?  Вы уж определитесь и отредактируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по
[документации](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#operators),
должно быть как-то так:

```js
User.findAll(
  where: {
    roles: {
      [Op.contains]: ['USER'],
    },
  },
)
```